# SQL Server ML Services user doesn't have access to package. (prophet)

Tags: facebook-prophet, sql-server-ml-services

I am using stored procedures to call python scripts in SQL Server ML Services.
I have a number of stored procedures/models currently successfully deployed however when trying to use prophet for some forecasting I am getting this error

PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.PRD01\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\site-packages\prophet'

This is the same directory as my other packages are installed, and when I read in a csv from the same  location this is successful so think the problem lies with ML services/prophet.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.